# How to pass update UI value in buildResults of SearchDelegate?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-application

I am trying to show real time http json data `mtgCardNames` using `buildResults`. The data seem to be passed down successfully (they are printed out correctly) but somehow they are not displayed on the screen. To understand the situation, I tried to display some other data (search `query` and `testList`), they show on the screen as expected.

Why is this happening?

I overrided all the required 4 methods, but only paste the `buildResults` here to be brief.

```
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    List<MTGCard> mtgCards = [];
    List<Text> mtgCardNames = [];
    GetHTTP getHTTP = GetHTTP();
    getHTTP.getData().then((usersFromServer) {
      mtgCards = usersFromServer;
      for (MTGCard c in mtgCards){
        print(c.name);    // <= can print out as expected
        mtgCardNames.add(Text(c.name));
      }
    });
    List<Text> testList = [
      Text('a'),
      Text('aa'),
      Text('aaa'),
    ];

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(query),
        Column(
          children: mtgCardNames,
        ),
        Column(
          children: testList,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

[image: UI]

For this moment, the http data is not based on the query, it is hard coded url but real time data. I am running on Ubuntu and my flutter doctor shows no issue.

**Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated!**

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, the data is fetched properly, since they can be printed out as expected. But they are just not showing on the screen.

Comment: `then(...)` is executed after network call returns response, but `return Column(...)` is executed immediately. So you don't see result of network call in column. Consider using approach from tutorial I linked

Comment: You can also print mtgCards or mtgCardNames just before `return Column(...)` to check that

Comment: Thank you! can you tell me how to fix it? I tried moving the return inside then() but the buildResults method need a widget return. Yes, if I print mtgCardNames right before the return it won't work, but I don't understand why, that's also the reason I moved that for loop inside then.

Comment: One way is using `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Thank you! I will learn more about FutureBuilder then, I was frustrated with it and avoided using it...hm...I should not do that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211391/discussion-between-moon-and-pavel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that network call `getData()` is executed asynchronously:

1) You call `getData()`

2) Synchronous code continues to execute: `return Column(...)` is called while `mtgCardNames` is still empty

3) You see empty column on the screen

4) Network call finishes, `then(...)` is executed and `mtgCardNames` is populated

---

To actually display column with data from network call, you should return one widget while it's loading and another one after. One way is to use `FutureBuilder`. Basic idea is

```dart
@override
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
  GetHTTP getHTTP = GetHTTP();
  return FutureBuilder<List<MTGCard>>(
    future: getHTTP.getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Text('Loading...');
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(query),
          for (MTGCard c in snapshot.data)
            Text(c.name),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

But there are some more details. E.g. it’s not a good idea to put network call in a build() method. Also you can show some error widget if network call fails. See details in [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#why-is-fetchalbum-called-in-initstate)